# Alternatives to SwiftUI ForEach loop

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

I'm using a `ForEach` loop in SwiftUI to iterate over an array, creating views. However, due to what I assume is an XCode bug, accessing the current element of the loop slows XCode and my previews down significantly, which is just hard to work with.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative to a `ForEach` loop that achieves a similar effect?

Example:

```
ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { num in       //CAUSES BUGS AND EVERYTHING TO SLOW TO A HALT
    Text(String(num))
}


for i in 0...10 {                         //LOOKING FOR AN ALTERNATIVE SUCH AS THIS
    Text(String(i))
}
```

Comment: Iterate over an `Identifiable` array of data rather than a range.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: @jnpdx I did that, and the issue went away except for if I try casting the element as a String... i.e. `String(num)`... any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your code so I can see what you tried?

Comment: if this simple loop: `ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { num in
 Text(String(num))`
}
 //CAUSES BUGS AND EVERYTHING TO SLOW TO A HALT.
 Then there is something very very wrong with your system.
 You could try re-installing XCode.

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax is wrong, a ForEach for constant range looks like this

```
ForEach(0..<10) { i in
    Text("\(i)")
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, the syntax is correct. 
`0...10` returns a closed range that contains both of its bounds.
`0..<10` returns a half-open range that contains its lower bound but not its upper bound. `ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) {....}` is correct.

Comment: The id param needs to be a key that uniquely identifies the data, id:.\self is a mistake

Comment: the range `0...10` guarantees that the id will be absolutely unique.